# Unity3d apps on iPad2 require old prov. profile to run

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, provisioning, provisioning-profile, ipad-2

Recently I renewed my provisioning profile and the certificates. The problem that occurs now is that the previous Unity3d apps that were on the iPad2 now still require the old provisioning profile to **run**.

When I try to run one of the old apps nothing happens, except a quick flashing screen.
In the log it says: "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found"

There is no problem when building new apps. This all works just fine. It's just the old apps.

Normally I could rebuild the old apps, but of some of the apps I don't have a backup from anymore. So a solution would be great.

Any tips/tricks?

**Specs:**

- iPad2
- MacOS 10.7.3 (out of my head..)
- Xcode 4.3.2

If you need more info just ask.

Answer (score 0):

Did you renew an expired provisioning profile (like a developer one) or your developer membership?

Have you tried drag/drop the provisioning profile in your itunes lib and synch your device? Also check that you don't have conflicting profiles on your device.